# Why $\int_0^\infty x^n \, exp(-x) =o(1/x^2)$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, geometry

I am reading an Euclidean geometry text which, at some point, involved the behavior of a quantity of the form $\int_0^\infty x^n\, exp(-x)$. It says then that this quantity behaves like $o(1/x^2)$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty$.

I don't see why it is so. I mean, to me, we can expand $$x^n\, exp(-x)=x^n \, (1-x +\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+...)$$ and while I can see that this could indeed converge (both intuitively from the $e^{-x}$ and from the fact it's an alternate series), I don't see how this reduced to an $o(1/x^2)$ behavior. If indeed we get an $o(1/x^2)$ then I agree that from Riemann's criteria, it would converge, but to get it in the first place is blurry to me. Any suggestion perhaps?

Comment: Note the difference between $O(1/x^2)$ and $o(1/x^2)$. The latter means that the function tends faster towards $0$ than $1/x^2$

Comment: Thanks @Peter for pointing this out. But why $o(1/x^2)$ and not , say, $o(1/x)$ or $o(1/x^7)$. I feel like I'm missing a step in understanding the process in-between, but not sure which exactly.

Comment: In fact, the other possibilities are true as well.

Comment: That's exactly my point. If, for example, we accept $o(1/x)$ then the integral can't be said to converge, so we need at least higher or equal than 2, no?

Comment: Oops, I did not notice the integral, in the title only the integrand is mentioned.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Edit done, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but how does $\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^n \, dx$ depend in any way on $x$?

Comment: If you are interested in the asymptotic behavior of the integrand (which proves the improper integral converges) then see below.  Otherwise get the question straight and I'll delete.

Comment: The question stated above is stated properly, and I do think that the answer below is probably the right answer, just checking some calculation before accepting it.

Comment: @Peter:  That would be tough since $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} \, dx = \Gamma(n+1) = n!$

Comment: @RRL OK, you are right. So, probably, your answer hits the intent of the question.

Comment: @Faissal But the integral does not depend on $x$, right ? So, $o(1/x^2)$ makes no sense. So, the $o(1/x^2)$ should apply to the integrand, then the question makes sense.

Comment: @Peter, the integral does indeed depends on x, it's not a typo. But as I said, I do think that RRL's answer explains what's happening (pls see my comment below under his answer, if I am not mistaken)

Comment: The integral is $n!$ as mentioned by $RRL$, so does not depend on $x$

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I think, it just confirms the statement in the title, which is about showing that the integral does not diverge. In this textbook, after a quick check it seems that the Gamma function was not assumed to be known, so that's why perhaps they showed the "non-divergence" that way. Otherwise, as you and RRL said, the answer would be a straight Gamma function, which, for fixed n, converges...and is independent of x, completely agree on this.

Comment: @Faissal Exactly, the function is compared to the $1/x^2$ function for which the integral converges to show that the given integral converges without using the gamma-function.

Comment: Thanks very much guys, this discussion was really helpful. It's much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Using the expansion $\displaystyle e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \ldots$ with $x > 0$,

$$e^x > \frac{x^{n+3}}{(n+3)!} \implies \frac{x^n e^{-x}}{1/x^2 } < \frac{(n+3)!}{x}$$

Comment: Yes I think I see what's going on. So technically you have $$\frac{x^n\,e^{-x}}{1}<\frac{(n+2)!}{x^2}$$ so then, asymptotically in x, and for fixed $n$ you get the required behavior. Many thanks RRL.

Comment: @Faissal:  You're welcome. More precisely $f(x) = o(1/x^2)$ as $x \to \infty$ (little-oh) means $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2f(x) \to 0$.  So the hint is leading to what I added above.